# Закрасить штриховую строку SVG при прокрутке и удалить закрашивание при прокрутке вверх

Tags: javascript, css, svg, анимация, css-animation

Я пытаюсь сделать `dashed` линию SVG штрихом на веб-странице и мне нужно заполнить этот штрих при прокрутке вниз, а во время прокрутки вверх снова медленно убрать залитый цвет.

Ниже приведен пример веб-сайта с эффектом прокрутки. Мне нужен такой же эффект
https://asaro.co.uk/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ниже мой код:

```html
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="802.354" height="3245.896" viewBox="0 0 802.354 3245.896">
  <path id="Path_440" data-name="Path 440" d="M14581.822,1364S14348,1448,14528,1848s-408,592-408,592-392,484,232,548,412,460,412,460-144,264-464,252-144,464-144,464,36,336,384,444" transform="translate(-13997.437 -1363.059)" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="8"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/54500703/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Я использую `path` дважды. Первый раз с `stroke-dasharray = "8"`. Второй раз `stroke-dasharray` элемента `use` имеет то же значение, что и длина `path`. 
Я надеюсь, что это то, что вам нужно.

```js
let l = Path_440.getTotalLength();
let dasharray = l;
let dashoffset = l;
theFill.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-dasharray", l);
theFill.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-dashoffset", l);
wrap.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  dashoffset = l - this.scrollTop * l / (this.scrollHeight - this.clientHeight);
  theFill.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-dashoffset", dashoffset);
});
```

```css
#wrap{height:100vh; overflow:scroll;}
```

```html
<div id="wrap"> 
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 802.354 3245.896">
   <defs>
  <path id="Path_440" d="M14581.822,1364S14348,1448,14528,1848s-408,592-408,592-392,484,232,548,412,460,412,460-144,264-464,252-144,464-144,464,36,336,384,444" transform="translate(-13997.437 -1363.059)" fill="none" /></defs>
        
<use xlink:href="#Path_440" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="8"/>
   
<use id="theFill" xlink:href="#Path_440" stroke="#000" stroke-width="3"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: под путем имеется ввиду элемент `path`? может стоило оставить его как `path`, или это общеупотребляемая терминология?

Comment: @Grundy и так `путь`, и так `path` общеупотребительно в техн. литературе. Мало того описательный термин  `sub path` используется в русской техн. литературе =`подпути` :)) могу исправить для лучшего понимания новичкам

Comment: Мне кажется, что новичку будет понятнее именно path, тк это название имеет прямую ассоциацию с кодом.